# Pushing a value to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't seem to figure out as to why I am unable to append a value to my array below? Is there a special syntax to follow or something when constructing an array like in the method used below?

```
var arr = {
    "fruits": ['apple','banana','orange']
};

arr.push({ "fruits":"testing123"}); // This line fails

alert(arr["fruits"]);
```

Comment: arr is not a array

Comment: You've created an object, not an array. Change arr to `[{
    "fruits": ['apple','banana','orange']
}];` in your opening declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array` defintion is all wrong. Assuming you want `arr` to be an `object` that has an `array` under `fruits` and then push another value inside `fruits`, use the following:

```js
var arr = {
    fruits: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
};
arr.fruits.push("testing123");
console.log(arr["fruits"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:  `arr.fruits.push("mango");`

Answer (score 2):

You can't `push()` to an object. You should either use the key-value notation:

```
arr.anotherFruits = "testing123"; // another key
arr.fruits = "testing123"; //to overwrite
```

Or make `arr` actually array:

```
var arr = [
    {"fruits": ['apple','banana','orange']}
]

arr.push({ "fruits":"testing123"})

alert(arr["fruits"])
```

In this case you'd get

```
var arr = [
    {"fruits": ['apple','banana','orange']},
    {"fruits":"testing123"}
]
```

Or in case you did want to get an object like this

```
var arr = {
    "fruits": ['apple','banana','orange','testing123']
}
```

you should've used `arr.fruits.push('testing123');`

Comment: wrong, cuz then he'll overwrite that array under the `fruits` key

Comment: @LorDex That's depending on what OP wants to do?

Comment: this would not fail:  arr.push({ "fruits":"testing123"}) ;  it just would add an object to the arr

Answer (score 0):

Change your initial arr declaration to this...

```
var arr = [{
    "fruits": ['apple','banana','orange']
}];
```

Then you can push more objects onto it. E.g.

```
arr.push({"fruits": ['mango', 'pear', 'tomato']});
```

Or, if you wish to push fruits to the existing array INSIDE your object, then simply use your existing arr declaration and use it like this...

```
arr.fruits.push('tomato');
arr.fruits.push('pear');
arr.fruits.push('tomato');
```

I'd argue that you don't really require this to be an object at all here.

All you need is this...

```
var fruits = [];
fruits.push('banana');
fruits.push('apple');
```

It's simply an array of fruits. If you need more complex structure, then use an array of objects, instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Array has `push()` method, but Object does not. Here you create an Object, but not an Array. So it failed.